# Patch files for Linux Kernel 2.6

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, patch

I am doing some data analysis on the code base of Linux kernel version 2.6. However I noticed that in the kernel website (https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/) patch files are missing after 2.6.13.1. So how do I get the patch files for 2.6.14-2.6.39 versions of the kernel?

Comment: Linux kernels all the way up to 39 are in there, just no patches.  Maybe they decided that the patches weren't worth the effort

Comment: @Mokubai - Actually they have patches starting with 3.0 again. It's only 2.6.14-39 releases that's missing. I wonder what's the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate patch files yourselves using the full git repositories at https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/history/history.git/ (for versions up to 2.6.12-rc2) and https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/.

Once you have cloned the `linux` repository, you can create patch files using git:

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
cd linux
# Patch (based on the first version in series)
git diff v2.6.13..v2.6.13.2 > patch-2.6.13.2
# Incremental patch
git diff v2.6.13.1..v2.6.13.2 > patch-2.6.13.1-2
```

Comment: That would solve my problem. Thanks much man.